# Python: Match whole words in string and append to list in the order found

Tags: python, regex, string, search, match

Really need some help on this please-

I have a list:

```
mylist = "Cell Contents (Column Percentage, Counts, Statistical Test Results), Statistics (Overlap)"
```

I would like to find the following words in mylist:

```
'Statistical Test Results'
'Counts'
'Column Percentage'
```

Once found, I would like append those words to a new list in the order they appeared in mylist. So the new list should read:

```
newlist = ['Column Percentage','Counts','Statistical Test Results']
```

I know how to find a single word and append it to a new list using a for loop and in but I not too sure how to find multiple words and append them in the order they were found in the original list.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for specific terms, or just any words?  How do you know which words you are looking for?  You can easily find them using regular expressions.

Comment: I'm looking for these words: 'Statistical Test Results', 'Counts' , 'Column Percentage'. They will definitely appear in 'mylist' but their order may change.

Comment: Is `mylist` actually a list or a string?

Comment: `mylist` is not a list, but a string. Are you having list in the form of string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I matched the content between 1st pair of parentheses:

```
re.finditer(r'\((.*?)\)', mylist).next().groups()[0].split(', ')
['Column Percentage', 'Counts', 'Statistical Test Results']
```

`re.finditer` is [a regular expression search](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=finditer#re.finditer):

- the 1st parameter is the pattern: it tells to search the 1st item between parentheses
- note the use of the `?` inside to make it non-greedy, to avoid matching too large... To understand, remove it and test
- we want to capture the expression inside parentheses, that's why we have... parentheses inside the pattern. Note the difference between the escaped parentheses `\(` and `\)` that match in the string, and the capturing ones `(` and `)` not escaped.

`finditer` returns an iterator, it has effect only after we make it run with `next`. Now we want to get the captured part of the string: this is the `groups` method (`[0]` to get the 1st and only one, but you can capture several parts with regular expressions).

Then we just split the result by coma, and we're done !

Comment: That works thanks a lot! Would you mind telling me whats going on here so I can learn please?

Comment: Why `finditer().next()` instead of `search()`?

Comment: @Boosted_d16: Thanks for accepting ! I edited my question to detail it. @Tim: I just wanted the 1st one, that's why, but I agree I could use `re.search` or `re.findall` too.